# Reaction Of Grignard's Reagent with Acyl Chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, grignard-reagent

My organic chemistry book says that Grignard reagents react with acyl chloride just as hydride reagents.[image: Theory]

Further in an in-text question

[image: Question]

now using above theory, my answer is

[image: My Answer]

But Answer in Solution Manual Is

[image: Solution Manual's Answer]

Comment: It seems to be a mistake on their front.. What you have gotten is correct.

Comment: Safdar is right. It is not possible to add a vinyl group with a Grignard containing three C atoms

Comment: This is clearly an error in the book. Your answer is correct.

Comment: You may write the author or the editor of the book at the publishers about your find to consider a correction for future editions of the book.  Some keep a compilation of _errata_ available to the public (e.g., http://www.uky.edu/~rbgros1/textbook.html).  A check if there is a newer edition than the one in your hands may be useful, though.

Comment: Please add a citation for the textbook you are using. Also consider applying [tag:erratum].